# VisualStudio/Fortran parallelization causing "This app can’t run on this PC" Error?

Tags: visual-studio, parallel-processing, model, fortran

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed on a modeling workstation, along with Portland Group’s PVF fortran (PGI Visual Fortran) version 18.7.

The code is written in Fortran, and I have converted some of it to F95 syntax.

The workstation has x64 OS, and I am trying to compile in x64.

I am not sure of all of the settings I need in compiling.  I added a subroutine in which I want to start experimenting with parallelization.  However, the current problem is that I compile successfully, but when I try to run the code, I get the error: “This app can’t run on this PC.”  It is possible that the minimal parallelization directives that I included cause a problem, but online searches talk about x64 and x32 compatibility issues.  I am not sure that those items are pertinent because they talk about installing and running commercial software.

Has anyone ever run into this error in compiling code in whatever language?  If so, do you have a clue about the cause?

Comment: Have you tried compiling, linking and running a very simple "hello world" program? Does that work?

Comment: You haven't stated how you are running the code - from within Visual Studio, from command line, by double clicking, from a batch file etc.  It may be that the method you are choosing is trying to run a 64-bit program from a 32-bit cmd prompt.